# Comparing elements in a list in Python's for -loop

Tags: python, list

**What is wrong in the method `end` in the code?**

The method `end` returns always *1* although it should return *0* with the current data.

```
# return 1 if the sum of four consecutive elements equal the sum over other sum of the other three sums
# else return 0
# Eg the current sums "35 34 34 34" should return 0    

data = "2|15|14|4|12|6|7|9|8|10|11|5|13|3|2|16"
arra = data.split("|");

def do_row ( arra, n ):
        return arra[4*n:4 + 4*n]

def row_summa (row):
        return sum(map(int,row))

def end ( summat ):                                     # problem here!
        equality = 1 
        for i in summat[2:5]:
                print "Comparing: ", summat[1], " and ", i, ".\n"
                if summat[1] != i:
                        equality = 0 
        print equality

for i in range(0,4):
        summat = []
        summat.append( row_summa( do_row(arra,i) ) ) 
        print row_summa ( do_row(arra,i) )
        summa = 0 

end(summat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also study this piece of code

```
data = "2|15|14|4|12|6|7|9|8|10|11|5|13|3|2|16"
arra = map(int,data.split("|"))
summat = [sum(arra[i:i+4]) for i in range(0,len(arra),4)]
print summat
print len(set(summat))==1
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really tell what you're trying to do here, but I can certainly say why `end()` returns 1 instead of 0. In your last `for` loop, you reset `summat` to `[]` at the start of the loop, so at the end, summat only contains a single value (the one you most recently appended on). So when you ask for `summat[2:5]` on a list of a single item, Python returns an empty list (as there are no values in that range) - in which case there are no chances for `equality` to be set to zero because the loop in `end` never runs.

Comment: That last `for` loop isn't part of the `end()` function.

Comment: Jack didn't claim it was.  The for loop sets summat to an empty list every iteration.  After the for loop has finished, end is called with summat as its argument.  So, summat will only ever have one element in it: the return from row_summa(do_row(arra, i)) in the last iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have an off-by-one error. Remember that array indexes in Python start at 0, not 1. So where you do this:

```
   for i in summat[2:5]:
            print "Comparing: ", summat[1], " and ", i, ".\n"
            if summat[1] != i:
                    equality = 0
```

you are not looking at `summat[0]` at all. Try perhaps:

```
   for i in summat[1:4]:
            print "Comparing: ", summat[0], " and ", i, ".\n"
            if summat[0] != i:
                    equality = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `end` doesn't return 1.  It returns `None`.  It *prints* 1.  Kind of deceptive if you're running it from the command line.

Second, when you call `end`, `summat` is equal to `[34]`.  So this:

```
for i in summat[2:5]:
```

never even executes.  It won't do anything unless `summat` contains at least 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. Initialising summat to [] inside the loop, also the off by one error Greg mentioned

```
data = "2|15|14|4|12|6|7|9|8|10|11|5|13|3|2|16"
arra = data.split("|");

def do_row ( arra, n ):
        return arra[4*n:4 + 4*n]

def row_summa (row):
        return sum(map(int,row))

def end ( summat ):                                     # problem here!
        equality = 1 
        for i in summat[1:]:  # 1 <=== IS THE SECOND ELEMENT
                print "Comparing: ", summat[0], " and ", i, ".\n"
                if summat[0] != i:
                        equality = 0 
        print equality

summat = []        # <=== DO THIS BEFORE THE LOOP
for i in range(0,4):
        summat.append( row_summa( do_row(arra,i) ) ) 
        print row_summa ( do_row(arra,i) )
        summa = 0 

end(summat)
```